# whats wrong with this code in firebase and android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 usersRef= myRef.child("users");
        usersRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo("yair").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                User user=new User();
                user.setName(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getName());
                user.setEmail(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getEmail());
                user.setId(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getId());
                user.setPhone_num(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getPhone_num());
```

my firebase looks like that:

```
users
 Y6NKciGllTgkLXlMj9YLlAFuw522
 email: 
"yk.yair@gmail.com"
 id: 
"Y6NKciGllTgkLXlMj9YLlAFuw522"
 name: 
"yair"
 phone_num: 
"050-7777151"
 kfby10Wy16Rx12v7Mx0sksqUTE72
 email: 
"aaa"
 id: 
"kfby10Wy16Rx12v7Mx0sksqUTE72"
 name: 
"aaa"
 phone_num: 
"(050)7777151"
```

it seems that the user always stays null;
can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String email = ds.child("email").getValue(String.class);
            User user = new User();
            user.setEmail(email);
            //and so on
            Log.d("TAG", email);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

You output will be:

```
yk.yair@gmail.com
```

Another approach will be just to change the `DatabaseReference` and use the same code like this:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users").child(userId);
```

In which `userId` is the unique id generated by the `push()` method.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users").orderByChild("name").equalTo("yair").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null){
                Log.i("IS NULL", "IS NULL");
            } else{
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                Log.i("user name", user.getName());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

and make sure that your database is structured like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt8ml.png)